# MXSegmentedPagerControllerDataSource adopted by view controller but viewControllerForPageAt not called instead have to use function viewForPageAt

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, viewcontroller

Using https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager library following is my code

```
class StoreDetailsViewController: UIViewController ,MXSegmentedPagerDelegate, MXSegmentedPagerControllerDataSource, MXParallaxHeaderDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITextViewDelegate
```

Now I am using protocol MXSegmentedPagerControllerDataSource and it is making compulsory to add following stubs

```
func segmentedPager(_ segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, viewForPageAt index: Int) -> UIView {
    return viewControllerArray[index].view
}

func segmentedPager(_ segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, segueIdentifierForPageAt index: Int) -> String {
    return  ""
}
```

and following stub is ignored viewControllerForPageAt

```
func segmentedPager(_ segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, viewControllerForPageAt index: 
 Int) -> UIViewController {

    return viewControllerArray[index]
}
```

Comment: Quick look at MXSegmentedPager library -- it manages / shows **views** not **view controllers**.

Comment: it manages both